# Why do I get the error, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, webforms

This is homework, a math game/quiz that populates the text boxes with random numbers instead of the question marks.  It's an ASP.NET Web Form in Visual Studio 2012 using C#.  The requirement is to use some type of storage, so I'm using "Application" to store the user's name and their score, and when they click "Check Results," the Results panel will display their name and the score.  The error is on this line of the code behind:  `Ranking.Add(NameText.Text, Score);`, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."  Thanks in advance!!!

[image: Layout of Math Game]

HTML:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MathGame.aspx.cs" Inherits="MvcApplication3.MathGame" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #MathGame {
            height: 404px;
            width: 505px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

        <asp:Panel ID="PanelGame" runat="server">
        <form id="MathGame" runat="server">
        <div>
        <asp:Label runat="server" BorderStyle="None" Font-Names="Microsoft Sans Serif" Font-Size="18pt" style="z-index: 1; top: 142px; position: absolute; height: 33px; text-align: center; right: 762px; margin-right: 87px; bottom: 312px; width: 2px; left: 145px;" Text="-"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="plusLeftLabel" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Names="Microsoft Sans Serif" Font-Size="18pt" style="z-index: 1; left: 48px; top: 75px; position: absolute; height: 33px; text-align: center; margin-right: 87px" Text="?" Width="60px"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="plusRightLabel" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Names="Microsoft Sans Serif" Font-Size="18pt" style="z-index: 1; left: 193px; top: 75px; position: absolute; height: 33px; text-align: center; margin-right: 87px" Text="?" Width="60px"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label runat="server" BorderStyle="None" Font-Names="Microsoft Sans Serif" Font-Size="18pt" style="z-index: 1; left: 270px; top: 208px; position: absolute; height: 33px; text-align: center; margin-right: 87px" Text="=" Width="60px"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Button ID="startButton" runat="server" Font-Size="14pt" style="z-index: 1; left: 265px; top: 379px; position: absolute; height: 34px;" TabIndex="1" Text="Check Results" OnClick="startButton_Click1" ValidationGroup="FormValidation" />

        <asp:Label ID="dividedLeftLabel" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Names="Microsoft Sans Serif" Font-Size="18pt" style="z-index: 1; left: 47px; top: 262px; position: absolute; height: 33px; text-align: center; margin-right: 87px; right: 717px;" Text="?" Width="60px"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="minusLeftLabel" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Names="Microsoft Sans Serif" Font-Size="18pt" style="z-index: 1; left: 48px; top: 139px; position: absolute; height: 33px; text-align: center; margin-right: 87px" Text="?" Width="60px"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="timesLeftLabel" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Names="Microsoft Sans Serif" Font-Size="18pt" style="z-index: 1; left: 47px; top: 201px; position: absolute; height: 33px; text-align: center; margin-right: 87px; bottom: 315px;" Text="?" Width="60px"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label runat="server" BorderStyle="None" Font-Names="Microsoft Sans Serif" Font-Size="18pt" style="z-index: 1; top: 83px; position: absolute; height: 33px; text-align: center; right: 667px; margin-right: 87px; left: 145px; bottom: 426px;" Text="+" Width="20px"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label runat="server" BorderStyle="None" Font-Names="Microsoft Sans Serif" Font-Size="18pt" style="z-index: 1; top: 269px; position: absolute; height: 33px; text-align: center; right: 667px; margin-right: 87px; left: 145px;" Text="÷" Width="20px"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label runat="server" BorderStyle="None" Font-Names="Microsoft Sans Serif" Font-Size="18pt" style="z-index: 1; top: 205px; position: absolute; height: 33px; text-align: center; right: 750px; margin-right: 87px; left: 145px;" Text="x" Width="20px"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="dividedRightLabel" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Names="Microsoft Sans Serif" Font-Size="18pt" style="z-index: 1; left: 193px; top: 262px; position: absolute; height: 33px; text-align: center; margin-right: 87px" Text="?" Width="60px"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="minusRightLabel" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Names="Microsoft Sans Serif" Font-Size="18pt" style="z-index: 1; left: 193px; top: 138px; position: absolute; height: 33px; text-align: center; margin-right: 87px" Text="?" Width="60px"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="timesRightLabel" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Names="Microsoft Sans Serif" Font-Size="18pt" style="z-index: 1; left: 192px; top: 202px; position: absolute; height: 33px; text-align: center; margin-right: 87px" Text="?" Width="60px"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label runat="server" BorderStyle="None" Font-Names="Microsoft Sans Serif" Font-Size="18pt" style="z-index: 1; left: 269px; top: 82px; position: absolute; height: 33px; text-align: center; margin-right: 87px; width: 60px;" Text="="></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label runat="server" BorderStyle="None" Font-Names="Microsoft Sans Serif" Font-Size="18pt" style="z-index: 1; left: 270px; top: 269px; position: absolute; height: 33px; text-align: center; margin-right: 87px" Text="=" Width="60px"></asp:Label>

        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 49px; top: 333px; position: absolute; height: 19px; width: 367px">
        <br />Please enter your name: <asp:TextBox ID="NameText" runat="server" Height="17px"></asp:TextBox><asp:RequiredFieldValidator EnableClientScript="false" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="<br />Your name is required." ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="NameText" ValidationGroup="FormValidation"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></asp:Panel>

        <asp:Label runat="server" BorderStyle="None" Font-Names="Microsoft Sans Serif" Font-Size="18pt" style="z-index: 1; left: 269px; top: 147px; position: absolute; height: 33px; text-align: center; margin-right: 87px" Text="=" Width="60px" ID="Label1"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TimesResult" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 324px; top: 210px; position: absolute; width: 87px; height: 19px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="MinusResult" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 324px; top: 146px; position: absolute; width: 87px; height: 19px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="DivideResult" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 324px; top: 269px; position: absolute; width: 87px; height: 19px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="PlusResult" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 324px; top: 81px; position: absolute; width: 87px; height: 19px"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form></asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel ID="PanelRanking" runat="server">
        <asp:BulletedList ID="RankingList" runat="server">
        </asp:BulletedList>
    </asp:Panel>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace MvcApplication3
{
    public partial class MathGame : System.Web.UI.Page
    {   
        // Create a Random object to generate random numbers.
        Random randomizer = new Random();

        public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PanelRanking.Visible = false;
            plusLeftLabel.Text = randomizer.Next(51).ToString();
            plusRightLabel.Text = randomizer.Next(51).ToString();
            minusLeftLabel.Text = randomizer.Next(51).ToString();
            minusRightLabel.Text = randomizer.Next(51).ToString();
            timesLeftLabel.Text = randomizer.Next(51).ToString();
            timesRightLabel.Text = randomizer.Next(51).ToString();
            dividedLeftLabel.Text = randomizer.Next(51).ToString();
            dividedRightLabel.Text = randomizer.Next(51).ToString();
        }

        public void startButton_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int Score = 0;
            // Check the answers

            if (int.Parse(plusLeftLabel.Text) + int.Parse(plusRightLabel.Text) == int.Parse(PlusResult.Text))
                Score += 1;

            if (int.Parse(minusLeftLabel.Text) - int.Parse(minusRightLabel.Text) == int.Parse(MinusResult.Text))
                Score += 1;

            if (int.Parse(timesLeftLabel.Text) + int.Parse(timesRightLabel.Text) == int.Parse(TimesResult.Text))
                Score += 1;

            if (int.Parse(dividedLeftLabel.Text) + int.Parse(dividedRightLabel.Text) == int.Parse(DivideResult.Text))
                Score += 1;

            Dictionary<string, int> Ranking = (Dictionary<string, int>)Application["Ranking"];
            *Ranking.Add(NameText.Text, Score);*
            Application.Lock();
            Application["Ranking"] = Ranking;
            Application.UnLock();

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> element in Ranking){
                RankingList.Items.Add(element.ToString());
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint and step through the execution of the code. I suspect the issue is actually on the line before and that `Ranking` will be `null`.

Comment: `Ranking` or `NameText`

Comment: The HTML and screenshot are unnecessary here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using `Application["Ranking"]` directly. please check it against null before using it.

```
if(Application["Ranking"] != null){
}
```

Comment: Thanks. When I ran it, filled in the answers & name, then clicked the button, I got a blank pg. I'll step through & look at it to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Is this all of your code?  What is`(Dictionary<string, int>)Application["Ranking"];` referencing?  Where is that data initialized?

You probably need to initialize it somewhere, or else its going to return null and `Ranking.Add()` will be trying to add to a null object.

Comment: What would the syntax be to initialize it?